# Who is setting http_proxy?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, environment-variables

On an Ubuntu system with bash as the default shell for the interested user, the `http_proxy` environment variable is set to a specific value in a fresh GNOME Terminal.

The `.bashrc` file for this user and the one common to all users are not setting this value. A recursive grep looking for the proxy specific value from the root file system is running, but will take hours to complete.

What are the common places I can look at to know where this proxy value is set ?

Comment: Is NetworkManager setting it? Assuming you're using it to manage your network connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is NetworkManager setting it? Assuming you're using it to manage your network connection. Also you can invoke a shell like this in debug mode so you can get some context of other things happening around the setting of this variable.

#### Example

```
$ bash -x
+ '[' -f /etc/bashrc ']'
+ . /etc/bashrc
++ '[' '\s-\v\$ ' ']'
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ case $TERM in
++ '[' -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm ']'
++ '[' 3409 -ge 3405 ']'
++ PROMPT_COMMAND=__vte_prompt_command
++ shopt -s histappend
++ history -a
++ shopt -s checkwinsize
++ '[' '\s-\v\$ ' = '\s-\v\$ ' ']'
++ PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '
++ shopt -q login_shell
++ '[' 1000 -gt 199 ']'
+++ id -gn
+++ id -un
++ '[' saml = saml ']'
++ umask 002
++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/256term.sh ']'
...
```